# ZedGraph remove pie slice?

Tags: .net, zedgraph

I am trying to use the ZedGraphControl to create a pie chart. I am able to add pie slices by using the

```
zedGraphControl.GraphPane.AddPieSlice (30, Color.Red, Color.White, 45f, .0, "Data");
```

Method, but there does not seem to be any

```
RemovePieSlice
```

Or any remove object at all methods. Am I missing something simple, or does this library not allow for the removal of slices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddPieSlice` returns a `PieItem` object; the `PieItem` class inherits from `CurveItem`. This means you can remove the `PieItem` via the `CurveList` property (which is a collection of `CurveItem` objects).

To remove just one `PieItem` object:

```
Dim zgc As ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl = Me.ZedGraphControl1

Dim zgPane As ZedGraph.GraphPane = zgc.GraphPane

Dim zgPieItem As ZedGraph.PieItem = zgPane.CurveList("PieItemLabel")
zgPane.CurveList.Remove(zgPieItem)
```

To remove all `PieItem` objects:

```
Dim zgc As ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl = Me.ZedGraphControl1

Dim zgPane As ZedGraph.GraphPane = zgc.GraphPane

zgPane.CurveList.Clear()
```

Comment: Just found this myself. Calling

zedGraphControl.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();

Cleared all of the pie items.

Thanks.

Comment: @Zenox: Yes, but you can also remove a specific slice, if that's what you want. See the code I provided.